# LISP creating an array

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

When I use this function to create an array, I get the following error:

```
> (defun f1(lst)
   (setf m (make-array '((length lst) 3))))
F1
> (f1 '(1 2 3))
Error: Not a nonnegative integer - (LENGTH LST)
```

The length of the list should be a nonnegative integer, 3 in this case, so why am I getting this error and what can I do instead?

```
> (length '(1 2 3))
3
```

Answer (score 5):

You are quoting the list `((length lst) 3)))`, so its value is `((LENGTH LST) 3)))`, in which the first element is not a number but a two symbol list.

Use instead `list` to build a new list in which the first argument is evaluated:

```
CL-USER> (defun f1(lst) 
           (setf m (make-array (list (length lst) 3))))
F1
CL-USER> (f1 '(1 2 3))
#2A((0 0 0) (0 0 0) (0 0 0))
```

In Lisp languages `'((A) 3)` is an abbreviation for `(QUOTE ((A) 3))`, which is evaluated to `((A) 3)`. On the other hand, `(list (A) 3)` is evaluated regularly, evaluating `(A)` to the call of the function `A`, and producing at the end the list `(value-of-calling-a 3)`.